# facebook iframe compatibility jquery plugin list

Tags: jquery, facebook, plugins, module, xfbml

anyone can share their expiriance with jquery plugins and facebook iframe developing? please write here the plugin names that worked to you good so its will be a list of good-known plugins and will save time...

Answer (score 0):

You can use any jquery Iframe, there are lots of choices, fancybox has an iframe, simplebox, or just the HTML  will work.